# Problem in switching to python version using pyenv in windows system

Tags: python, windows, pyenv

I have installed pyenv in my **windows** system and updated it using `pyenv update`. When I run `pyenv --version` it shows **2.64.11**. I installed python 3.9.9 to use in some project using command `pyenv install 3.9.9`. Now I open my project in visual studio code and open terminal and run the some above commands like for checking version of pyenv and `pyenv versions` which shows me **3.9.9** in output.Now I am in one of the directory of the **D:/notification** folder. Now I run `pyenv local 3.9.9` and check by typing `pyenv versions` which shows me ***3.9.9** which means 3.9.9 version is set by pyenv for this directory and for its child directories. But in meantime if I run command `python --version` it shows me **3.8.3** result and this is the version which I have installed from the official python.org website. I don't know why it is behaving like that. When I move to one more directory down i.e. **D:/notification/notification** then also the above stated problem remains as it is. Please help me in fixing this issue.